# Slick.js is not working due some conflict with the other scripts used on the page

Tags: php, jquery, slider, slick.js

I am using many scripts on my page but due to some reason slick.js script is not working with those scripts.

when i remove all the other string then slick is working fine.

> Below is the body section

```
    `

<body>
  <section class="customer-logos slider">
   <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($response['urlToImage']) ; $i++) 
      { 
      ?>
      <div class="slide">

        <img src="<?php echo $response['urlToImage'][$i]; ?>" 
        height=200px 
       width=200px>
      </div>
      <?php }?>

   </section>
  </body>
```

> ALL the scripts below please check which script is creating problem

```
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick- 
    carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick- 
    carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick- 
    carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
          }]
         });
       });
     </script>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery.2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/1/theme.js"></script>

<script src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Page loads three jquery scripts and two owl carousel scripts. It's not okay.
Leave only one jquery and one owl.
P.s slick must be loaded after jquery